# Python Sockets, download is almost 10x the size of original file, upload is 0 bytes

Tags: python, c++, sockets, unix, google-drive-api

## Creating an Mobile application with embedded Python 2.7

### Using Marmalade C++ SDK.

I'm integrating connectivity to cloud file transfer services.

- FTP: file transfers work flawlessly
- Dropbox: authenticates then gives me: *socket [Errno 22] Invalid argument*
- Google Drive: Authenticates, lists metadata, but file transfers illicit some strange behavior

Since I've made all the bindings to the marmalade socket subsystem (unix like) but some features are unimplemented. To connect to Google Drive, initially I did some modifications to httplib2 / **init**.py, setting all instances of:

```
self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

#to this:

self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

After doing this little patch I could successfully connect and download metadata from Google Drive. However:

- When I upload a 7KB file, the file appears on Google Drive, but has a
  file size of 0 bytes
- When I download a 7KB file using urllib, I get a
  54KB file back

I know it must have to do with a misconfiguration of the socket properties, but not all properties are implemented. 
**[Here are some standard python test outputs (test_sockets , test_httplib )](http://pastebin.com/xrbCB7cX)**

Implementation here:
**[Marmalade /h/std/netdb.h](http://pastebin.com/yLDdCnKV)**

### Are there any that I should try as a viable replacement?

I don't have a clue.

**[From: unix-man setsockopt(2)](http://www.sbras.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?setsockopt%202)**

```
SO_DEBUG          enables recording of debugging information
SO_REUSEADDR       enables local address reuse
SO_REUSEPORT       enables duplicate address and port bindings
SO_KEEPALIVE       enables keep connections alive
SO_DONTROUTE       enables routing bypass for outgoing messages
SO_LINGER         linger on close if data present
SO_BROADCAST       enables permission to transmit broadcast messages
SO_OOBINLINE       enables reception of out-of-band data in band
SO_SNDBUF         set buffer size for output
SO_RCVBUF         set buffer size for input
SO_SNDLOWAT       set minimum count for output
SO_RCVLOWAT       set minimum count for input
SO_SNDTIMEO       set timeout value for output
SO_RCVTIMEO       set timeout value for input
SO_ACCEPTFILTER    set accept filter on listening socket
SO_TYPE       get the type of the socket (get only)
SO_ERROR          get and clear error on the socket (get only)
```

**[Here is my Google upload / download / listing source code](http://pastebin.com/P1dXRnqB)**

I'll brute force this until the problem is resolved, hopefully. Ill report back if I figure it out

Comment: Your description is quite confusing. Either original version with TCP_NODELAY and yours with SO_REUSEADDR essentially has nothing related to the described problems. TCP_NODELAY could only increase interactive exchange speed but HTTP doesn't really need it. SO_REUSEADDR doesn't affect connection, only port binding. I think to diagnose the issue you should capture network traffic and analyse it. You could expect spontaneous resets and/or multiple packet retransmissions.

Comment: It's much more likely that your code is majorly borken.

Comment: @Netch , ok  awesome, thanks for the explanation. I got that from the docs but I wasn't sure. That's what I wanted to hear. I'll go over my code again then do a packet capture.

Comment: @Martin James 
I'll keep looking in my code. But it's troubling that it works on windows just fine..... it's really not that complex http://pastebin.com/P1dXRnqB

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. it was 2 problems with my file handling code.

in uploading:

```
database_file = drive.CreateFile()
database_file['title'] = packageName
# this needs to be set
database_file.SetContentFile(packageName)
#
database_file['parents']=[{"kind": "drive#fileLink" ,'id': str(cloudfolderid) }]
```

In downloading, I was using the wrong url (webContentLink is for browsers only, use "downloadUrl" ). I also then needed to craft a header to authorize the download

```
import urllib2
import json


url = 'https://doc-14-5g-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/n4vedqgda15lkaommio7l899vgqu4k84/ugncmscf57d4r6f64b78or1g6b71168t/1409342400000/13487736009921291757/13487736009921291757/0B1umnT9WASfHUHpUaWVkc0xhNzA?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true'

#Parse saved credentials
credentialsFile = open('./configs/gcreds.dat', 'r')
rawJson =  credentialsFile.read()
credentialsFile.close()
values = json.loads(rawJson)

#Header must include: {"Authorization" : "Bearer xxxxxxx SomeToken xxxxx"}
ConstructedHeader = "Bearer " + str(values["token_response"]["access_token"])
Header = {"Authorization": ConstructedHeader}

req = urllib2.Request( url, headers= Header )
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

output = open("UploadTest.z.crypt",'wb')
output.write(response.read())
output.close()
```